# Windows Phone 8.1 Tab/Swipe controll

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am developing a Windows 8.1 Universal App and i'm searching for the Tab/Swipe control they use in the Swarm, Dropbox, Instagram Windows Phone apps.

I could make a UserControl with the same functionality but since they all use the same i think it's an existing control by Microsoft or an external library. I tried the Hub, FlipView and some other controls but i don't get it the same.

Here are the specifics:

- Tabs to go to view
- Swipe to go to view
- Looped scroll in both directions
- Data loading after swipe (you first see a white screen while loading, then you scroll to the correct view)

Here are screenshot's of the WP apps:
[image: Swarm]
[image: Dropbox]

Comment: Both These apps pretty sure use the Pivot Control. They just removed the header and placed a custom one instead. They used are the Pivots SelectionChanged and SelectedIndex.
Dropbox was made by Rudy Huyn. If you ask him directly on twitter, he may have a sample for you.

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed the Pivot control i was searching, because i started my controls in the shared code it was hidden. Now i see it in the shared code but with a warning (i did a reset of my visual studio).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess [this](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Tabbed_interface_with_Pivot_animation_for_Windows_Phone) is what you're looking for, ie: the `Tabbed Interface` for Pivot.

But before you use this, check the compatibility with your application. I'm not sure whether there are samples out there for WP8.1, if not you gotta make your own custom `Pivot` control.

[Reference](http://depblog.weblogs.us/2013/08/29/twitterate-your-windows-phone-app/)